# MKMapView - UIWebView as MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Is there a way to handle MKAnnotationView as being a container for html formatted text? Generally saying, I would like to control MKAnnotationView through a UIWebView, UIWebView to be the view of the MKAnnotationView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer myself, it might be done, in a very ugly manner, but effectively.
[Here you are.](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you'd like to have web views as your map annotations. You could try making a custom view for your annotation, and adding a web view as a subview of this. However this could get quite heavy memory wise so you wouldn't want too many of these on your map at once. If it's a standard view layout you're after you're better off building a native UI and populating it with downloaded data.